# highcharts single line with arrow arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would a chart where there is a single line arrow looking like this:

```
<-------X------------>
1    2    3    4    5
```

Or like this (where / is suppose to be an arrow :)):

```
           \/
 -------------------------
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
 -------------------------
```

I tried labbing a bit with this but without any results and I couldnt find any good example of this. Is there any good highcharts for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/o6cxfn5s/

Comment: still not clear what you want . But check http://jsfiddle.net/La6bh8gx/

Comment: So you want to have a line series with arrow(s) on the end(s) that indicate(s) direction?

Comment: @KamilKulig yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/u3qj6u74/

It contains wrapped core function responsible for drawing the graph:

```
  (function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {
      // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

      var arrowLength = 15,
        arrowWidth = 9,
        series = this,
        lastPoint = series.points[series.points.length - 1],
        nextLastPoint = series.points[series.points.length - 2],
        path = [];


      var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) / (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

      if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

      path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

      if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {
        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle));
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle));
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z');
      } else {
        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle));
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle));
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z');
      }

      if (series.arrow) {
        series.arrow.attr({
          d: path
        });
      } else {
        series.arrow = series.chart.renderer.path(path)
          .attr({
            fill: series.color
          })
          .add(series.group);
      }
    });
  }(Highcharts));
```

You can easily adjust this code so that there're arrows on both ends.

---

**Dosc page about wrapping**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts